# E2E tests that include database transactions fail randomly

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using TypeORM for PostgreSQL in my NestJS project.

For E2E tests, that have requests that do transactions, fail randomly. I added a timer after the transaction request of 50ms. After that, it works all of the time and doesn't fail randomly.

Could the transaction be the reason behind this lagging? That it takes some time to affect and the automated test fetches the data before the transaction?

My code improvised is something like:

```
request_that_triggers_transaction()

sleep(50ms)

request_that_fetches_what_transaction_changed()
```

If I remove the `sleep(50ms)`, the tests that include transactions fail randomly.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Please try to add a minimal reproduction code. Are you using 'awaits' properly, by the way?"